# How can I detect the end of the buffer when iterating over lines or headings in elisp?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

The TLDR is the code:

```
(while (?????)
    (org-next-visible-heading 1)
    (org-todo 'todo)
)
```

What should I put in the condition `?????` in order to stop at the end of the file, or after the last visible heading?

The longer context:

I'm using trying to use elisp to modify org-mode files for emacs. I'm new to elisp and finding it hard to find the relevant documentation for some basic things.

I want to iterate over the headings in an org-mode buffer and modify the status (i.e. todo) keyword. I've seen it suggested that if I want to modify the buffer, it is better not to use `org-element-map` but instead to use something like `org-next-visible-heading` or `org-forward-same-level`, and at each point use `org-todo` to modify the heading.

I know how to write a while loop, but I don't know how to write the condition as I  haven't been able to find out how to detect if I'm at the end of the buffer, even though this seems to be a trivial thing to want to do.

I'm happy to be told there is a better approach to my problem but I would still like to know how to detect the end of a buffer in general.

Comment: see `eobp` to check for end of buffer, eg. `(while (not (eobp)) ...)`

Comment: @Rorschach You should make that an Answer.  See also `C-h i g (elisp)Near Point`.

Comment: @Rorschach thank you! If you make it an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks also phils

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `org-map-entries` to map a function on each headline. There are some examples in the [doc](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Mapping-API.html#Using-the-Mapping-API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than looping, you can use `org-map-entries`. Here is an example, pretty much from the [doc](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Mapping-API.html#Using-the-Mapping-API), that marks each headline as a TODO item:

```el
(org-map-entries '(org-todo "TODO") t 'file 'archive 'comment)
```

It specifies a function to apply to each headline: `(org-todo "TODO")`; no tag or property matching; `file` scope; and skips `archive` and `comment` headlines.

Read the linked doc and also do `C-h f org-map-entries`, but don't get too scared by the doc string of the function: `org-map-entries` is very powerful, but it will take some time to understand how to do things with it and harness its power.

Comment: The couple of posts I was finding on the topic were suggesting not to use `org-map-entries` because it's not designed to modify and save a buffer, but is rather designed to return a new result. As a newbie I have no idea if this is accurate. But to be more specific I understand how to use `org-map-entries`; I don't know what to do with the result once I have it! Can I easily replace the current buffer with its output? I am stuck more on the easy than the hard things right now.

Comment: `org-map-entries` does (or does not) modify the buffer according to whether the function that it calls on each entry does (or does not) modify the buffer. It returns a list of return values of the function (one entry for each each headline). It will certainly *NOT* save the buffer: that's up to you. So I don't know what posts you refer to (if you can, please provide references), but they don't seem accurate to me, at least the way you describe them. The example I gave modifies the buffer by marking every headline as a TODO item. You can save that buffer as is into the same file (or a ...

Comment: ... different one if you prefer). Perhaps you are confusing it with `org-element-map` that you mention in your question?

Comment: NickD you're right, I'm confusing `org-map-entries` with `org-element-map`. If `org-map-entries` can modify the input buffer then I understand how to use it as a solution. Thanks! In answer to your question one example I was looking at was https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31011/how-to-modify-content-of-org-mode-document-using-org-element-api - but that is also about `org-element-map`

Comment: `org-element-map` takes a parse tree as input (an in-memory representation of an Org mode buffer - usually produced by evaluating `(org-element-parse-buffer)` in the buffer of interest: this calls returns the parse tree). It then walks the parse tree applying a function to each element it finds. Although the function can modify the parse tree, that is not its intended purpose: it is meant as a (quicker) way to get interesting information about the file without having to depend on lexical analysis only...

Comment: ...(i.e. on regexps): you parse the buffer once and (as long as it is not modified in the meantime) you can keep asking for interesting information about it. There is no support however for converting it back into an Org mode file, so there is no point in *modifying* the parse tree.